# Pipeline OrdinalEncoder ValueError Found unknown categories

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline, valueerror, ordinal

Please take it easy on me.  I’m switching careers into data science and don’t have a CS or programming background—so I could be doing something profoundly stupid.  I've researched for a few hours without success.

Objective: get Pipeline to run with OrdinalEncoder.

Problem: code does not run w/the OrdinalEncoder call.  It does run w/o OrdinalEncoder.  As best as I can tell I can pass two arguments, i.e. *categories* and *dtype*.  Neither help.

I’m passing the public [diabetes data](https://www.kaggle.com/saurabh00007/diabetescsv) set to the model.  Is this the issue?  IOW, is the passing of high cardinality features to OrdinalEncoder causing a problem between train/test data after model is built, i.e. the test split has a value that the train set does not?

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer()),
    ('ordinal_encoder', OrdinalEncoder()),
    ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(criterion='gini', n_estimators=100))])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

# Construct model
model = pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Show results
print("Hold-out AUC score: %.3f" %roc_auc_score(model.predict_proba(X_test),y_test))
```

Here’s the error I’m getting:

```
ValueError: Found unknown categories [17.0] in column 0 during transform
```

What am I doing wrong?

Setup:

```
The scikit-learn version is 0.20.2.
3.7.2 (v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 24 2018, 02:44:43) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Answer (score 24):

Your problem is that the model has encountered a value in the test data that it had not seen in the training data.  This is fine.  You just need to add the 'handle_unknown' argument to your encoder.

You should `fit` encoders and scalers to the training data (but not the test data) and then use them to `transform` both training and test data.  Thus, you must plan for the possibility of unexpected values in the test data.

Answer (score 11):

This will fix your problem:

```py
OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=-1)
```

Note that for this to work you have to be on Scikit Learn version 0.24 or above.

Comment: for some reason using `-1` instead of `np.nan` for `unknown_values`

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same problem, I just used `OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')` instead of `OneHotEncoder()` and the issue was fixed.

Comment: Note that for this to work you have to be on Scikit Learn version 0.24 or above.

Answer (score 5):

I'm late to the game but I landed on this page so I thought I would reply anyway.

You said it in your comment: "*diabetes dataset has too many values in many of the features for a given test/train split to both mirror all the values*"

This error happens with encoders when the testing set contains data not seen during the training.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think OrdinalEncoder is the correct choice in this situation. The diabetes dataset is comprised of continuous features, not categorical features. As stated in the documentation for [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html):

> The input to this transformer should be an array-like of integers or strings, denoting the values taken on by categorical (discrete) features.

That being said without additional output from the traceback or your setup I can't definitively say why you are getting the error you did. I was able to successfully split and execute the above code using the data loaded with the `load_diabetes` function. My guess is that in your case you did somehow miss fitting the encoder with the category "17.0", but again I would not recommend the use of a categorical encoder in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error during a `ColumnTransformer()` operation with an 'OneHoteEncoder()' I suspect it is because the encoder requires a 2D array to be input into the encoder.

You could try `.apply(lambda x: [x])` or some similar function to your ordinal values to increase their conditionality.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, encoding X before split in train and test worker for me. Encoding before split make all the categories being registered

Comment: Doing that would compromise the whole idea of a train/test set.
A test set is supposed to be a "real world" scenario in which you don't know what the new values are. So, you should instead incorporate an edge case for the encoding when it meets a new category. You can't "see into the future" and know what categories exist before you see them. That's a classic data leakage mistake I think.

Comment: Yes, I got aware of this recently, unless you have pre-defined categories in the column you shouldn't one hot encode them

Answer (score 0):

I would consider storing the ordinal values as json file during training and read the same encoding while testing. Any new value coming into the test data set which is not seen should be handled before testing or evaluating.

Answer (score 0):

In "Scikit Learn version 0.24" , Ordinal Encoder has two new Parameters :

`handle_unknown{‘error’, ‘use_encoded_value’}, default=’error’` and `unknown_value:{int or np.nan}, default=None`

Regarding both the Parameters, scikit-learn documentation states:

> When the parameter handle_unknown is set to ‘use_encoded_value’, this parameter is required and will set the encoded value of unknown categories. It has to be distinct from the values used to encode any of the categories in fit. If set to np.nan, the dtype parameter must be a float dtype.

Answer (score -1):

Use `fit_transform` instead of `fit` or `transform`. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).